# Programmatically translate chart in MPAndroidChart

Tags: java, android, user-interface, mpandroidchart

I'm trying to implement custom gesture logic for a CombinedChart in MPAndroidChart. Effectively, what I want to accomplish is to have a long press 'enable' highlighting of values but a short press & swipe just control panning / translating the chart (when zoomed). This would allow you to highlight values in a zoomed viewport without translating the chart (by long pressing before scrolling), but would also allow you to translate the chart if you wish by scrolling the view before the long press registers. **I have figured out how to do all of the gesture interactions I want however I cannot figure out how to translate the chart**.

All I'm really looking for is a API that allows me to translate the chart viewport by (dX, dY) in pixels but I can't seem to find anything. The closest I can find is CombinedChart.centerViewTo(...) but this expects you to center over **data point** values which if used when translating creates a bit of a staggered translation (as you cannot center over a value in-between two data points.

I can include code if needed, but I figured the code may be overly verbose for a simple API query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I'll delete this when / if  a better answer arises, but I found a way that suits my needs (yet may not be 'idiomatic'). What I did was the following:

(Given an offset in pixels of (dX, dY) and a CombinedChart named mChart...)

```
ViewPortHandler vph = mChart.getViewPortHandler();
Matrix transformation = vph.getMatrixTouch();
transformation.postTranslate(-dX, -dY); // unset the negs to make x / y inverted
vph.refresh(transformation, mChart, true);
```